# Lda Mallet returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, gensim, mallet

I am trying to code for a LDA Mallet Model...I ran this a couple months ago and it ran fine but it is no longer. There have been other posts on the same subject but the solutions have not yet helped me. Can anyone figure out what is wrong in my code and/or other solutions to fix the problem? The first two cells run fine. The third is where it breaks and it says it returns a non-zero exit status 1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So, the `mallet` command is failing. We have nowhere near enough information in this question to know why.

Comment: @pppery is there more information I can provide?

Answer (score 0):

The gensim wrapper in Python is creating a command-line call ("Command:..."). Something is going wrong with that, but the error message is not propagating back to Python.

You might try opening a Windows terminal and copying the command listed at the bottom (starting with "C:\Users..." to "...corpus.mallet") and seeing what it returns. There may be a missing file?